# Weird IE issue viewing the nav

Tags: internet-explorer

Good day and thank you for your time.

So if you could view my test site here http://unipedia.ca/ and see how it looks in IE - for some reason IE is making the menu display huge but testing it in Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera it displays normally.

Is there a way to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated - I feel like such a newbie!

Comment: looks fine in IE8 and IE8 in IE7 mode

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information.. languages you're coding the website with.. How are you setting the size's of the components etc..

If using css which you should be if using html you should specify the sizes in there. never through the html elements directly.. Also it depends on the css and html version with you are using.

CSS 3 and HTML 5 are not supported on all browsers at the moment (Unless they have finally all added support). What you need to do is post your css or code for where you are setting the size related settings for the menu..

Comment: OK well the site is powered by Wordpress. The mobilicity is powered by Twitter Boot Strap.

The doctype is XHTML+RDFa.



And this is the CSS at this address for easier reference.  http://unipedia.ca/styles-to-show.css

Oh and thank you.